# Can someone help to fix code for function arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

so iam trying to make a password strength checker but while trying to check for correct input length of password and then trying to test run the code it shows undefined name 'pwd' line 12.However I was unable to find how to fix this. Please help! Thank you.

```
def pwd_validate(pwd):
# Validate the length of the password
    while True:
        pwd = input("Please enter your new password, it should be 12 characters long: ")
        if len(pwd) == 12:
            print("""Thank you for entering a 12 charcter password 
            Now checking strength of password...""")
            break
        else:
            print("Password must contain only 12 characters please:")

pwd_validate(pwd)
```

Comment: Why have `pwd` as a parameter if you don't use it? Just change the definition to `def pwd_validate():`, then call as `pwd_validate()`.

Comment: What is it that are you passing to `pwd_validate`?  It can’t be the password that that function itself obtains from the user…

Answer (score -1):

The pwd you're passing to the function is not defined, it should be at least an empty string. Just define it before passing it to the function

```
def pwd_validate(pwd):
# Validate the length of the password
    while True:
        pwd = input("Please enter your new password, it should be 12 characters long: ")
        if len(pwd) == 12:
            print("""Thank you for entering a 12 charcter password 
            Now checking strength of password...""")
            break
        else:
            print("Password must contain only 12 characters please:")

pwd = ""
pwd_validate(pwd)
```

Comment: Although really, there's no reason to do this since `pwd` is set inside the function before it's used.

Comment: Yup, it's a diffrent way to do the same thing